# Passing the result of an array formula as a range into a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function like so

```
public function myFunc(r as range) as variant
...
end function
```

which I can call like so

```
=myFunc(A1:A10)
```

I wish to call the function like so

```
=myFunc(A1:A10+B1:B10)
```

It works with Excel functions like index(), say.  Also, when I click on Fx (the function wizard), it shows me that a range (which is the sum of each row 1..10) goes into myFunc.

I tried "ByVal r as Range" thinking that a reference may not be appropriate, but won't even enter myFunc.
Similarly, "r as Variant", while at least entering the code, gives nothing useful (contains Error 2015).

Comment: try: =myFunc(A1:B10)

Comment: Ha ha.  I wish for Excel to do the summing of A1:A10+B1:B10 for me, as opposed to having to do the tedium myself in VBA.  In real life, incidentally, the ranges are also not contiguous ;)

Comment: :) my bad, didn't realise your range would be non-contiguous. You could use a cell to define your ranges (maybe have the ranges comma separated). Then call your function as: `myFunc(A1)` (where `A1` is your temp cell). Then in your function, use `Union` to set you range

Comment: There are a great many things I could do - not least create a column C where I do the intermediate summing in the sheet.  What baffles me here is that I thought (until today) that "Range" was the universally correct type to interchange arrays between Excel and VBA.  Yet it does not seem so.  There is a trick I have missed all these years.  I seek to understand this trick.

Comment: Excel range is interchangeable as an array type with VBA. What you are looking for is how to pass a non-contiguous range. Try this: `=myFunc((A1:A10,C1:C10))`

Comment: Have you tired @Zac 's suggestion?.. I have same opinion e.g.  `Function RngCount(rng As Range)
RngCount = rng.Cells.Count
End Function` ..... returns 6 for .... `=RngCount((A2,B4,C6,D8:D10))`

Comment: Thanks Zac and Naresh.  I will have to consider these solutions now since the easier mnemonic simply won't work (without ctrl-shift-enter).  I am not enthused because, as I commented earlier, your approach condemns my VBA code to do the summing over the ranges.  Which is tedious in VBA, yet easy in native Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Some hard googling finds a duplicate query with an ugly answer:
[[Excel VBA: Passing a calculation result array as an argument to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36318972/excel-vba-passing-a-calculation-result-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function][1])
It seems I have to declare a variant and press Ctrl-Enter on myFunc.  Yuk !

Comment: Not only forces this a ghastly sheet usage, it also forces some truly horrific VBA code, which now must type-check whether a variant parameter is a Range or an array.  While this is the best answer I found, it cannot be the complete answer because the excel built-in functions manage without the awful Ctrl-Enter.

Comment: no ctrl + enter and ctrl + shift + enter, it depends on what you want to do, A1: A10 + B1: B10 returns a variant, it is not range

Comment: ctrl+shift-enter, you are right.  And what I want is no more than the same behaviour as is available in built-in functions.  Which do not require this nonsense.  It does not seem possible :(

Comment: `your question is Passing the result of an array formula as a range into a function`, which is impossible, which is inherently incorrect. Excel functions also do not work as you say. (I mean A1:A10 + B1:B10 is no longer a range)

Comment: How do you mean "inherently incorrect"?  You can try the original proposition with any built-in excel function and it will work just fine (ie without ctrl-shift-enter).  I understand now that A1:A10+B1:B10 is no longer a range.  And I would consider doing some ghastly type-recasting work *IF* there were no requirement for ctrl-shift-enter.  Since there appears to be, I won't - and don't quite know at this precise moment what I will do instead.  A1:A10+B1:B10 would have been nice...

Comment: I understand why you said it, but maybe someone will explain it better for you. If you already use vba you no longer need CSE unless you want to count an array of cells that look like this `{= myfunc (..)}` .This is unrelated to the passing parameter

Comment: ??  Why I said what?  I was checking the mnemonic on =index(A1:A10+B1:B10;...) - and it worked without CSE.  That raised my expectations that I should be able to accomplish the same with a UDF.  I was wrong.

Comment: In Excel there are some functions already working without CSE like sumproduct, I believe you won't need cse if you know what you need to calculate!